# How to find user who Drop any thing without auditing applied on database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, audit, flashback

In my scenario, I have a database with no flashback on, Only Archivelogs are active. No Auditing applied on database. 3 days ago some one drop all triggers, views, sequence from a specific user. Now is there any way to find out who did this? Can I go 3 days back without flashback on?

Comment: You can probably use Logminer. Be aware, it really isn't fun.. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/logminer.htm#SUTIL1565

Comment: the user has DBA privilege.

Comment: the parameter is set as audit_trail=DB

Comment: if you have archive logs, it is pretty easy to use logminer and find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Please try it:

```
Select * from user_audit_object
```

And for restore dropped table , you should know , that drop did without purge command.
If he/she used purge you can just restore your object just with dump or flashback and if he/she didn't use purge you can use this `select * from dba_recyclebin where orginal_name=<object_name>`, if the select has result you can restore that and otherwise just falshback or restore backup